# Validation rule confusion adding OR

Tags: validation, field-update

I have trouble writing validation rules in Salesforce. So I have a checkbox field **BypassWF__c** which when checked bypasses workflow. I have three fields **AssignedToUser__c**, **SupportUser1__c** and **SupportUser2__c**. So if any of these 3 fields is updated (ISCHANGED), an email alert will be sent. I'm able to do for 1 field:

```
 AND(
 NOT($User.BypassWF__c),
 OR(ISCHANGED(AssignedToUser__c), ISNEW())
 )
```

How do I add if any 1 or both **SupportUser1__c** and **SupportUser2__c** are updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` function takes as many logical expressions as you want, so you can simply do the following to check if any of the fields you mentioned have changed:

```
AND
(
    NOT($User.BypassWF__c),
    OR(ISCHANGED(AssignedToUser__c), ISCHANGED(SupportUser1__c), ISCHANGED(SupportUser2__c), ISNEW())
)
```

Further documentation for the `OR` function can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#OR).

> ## OR
>
> **Description**
>
> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns TRUE if any expression is true. Returns FALSE if all expressions are false. Use this function as an alternative to the operator `||` (OR).
>
> **Use**
>
> `OR(logical1, logical2...)` and replace any number of logical references with the expressions you want evaluated.

Comment: Thanks @alex-tennant. Its working. I often get confused when I have AND and OR in a formula. Any suggestions?

Comment: I often find that making sure you indent your formulas and reading them back to yourself in plain English helps, also thinking about what the inputs could be and working through the scenario. Sometimes reversing the order can help too, in this case the plain English version would be (you need to imagine the brackets): "If (AssignedToUser is changed OR SupportUser1 is changed... OR is a new record) AND Bypass__c is NOT TRUE (i.e. FALSE) then do something".

Comment: Just what I needed, the way to read through a big formula. Thank you very much.

Comment: I like to use && for AND and || for OR. I find it makes my formulas a lot more readable.